# Finding number of pairs of items from same list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to create a function where from a list of numbers, it tells me how many pairs of socks there are. Eg. in a list of [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20], it tells me there are 3 pairs, because 10x10 and 20x20 and 10x10, with 30, 50 and 20 being left over. But is enough for answer to simply be just '3'!

So this is my code so far, where 
n: the number of socks in the pile
ar: the colors of each sock

```
def sockMerchant(n, ar):
    ar = [10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20]
    n = len(ar)
    pair = []
    for i in ar:
        if ar.count >= 2 and (ar.count % 2) == 0:
            pair.append(i)
        if ar.count < 0:
            return False
    return (n,ar)
    print(len(pair))
```

However...code not quite there yet. Am i making a mistake in how i call the function? And how is my approach, in first testing whether the number appears at least twice and in even counts, to check for pairs? Please do advise me!

Comment: `arr.count` would be a syntax error in the given code... What are you counting? What is arr?

Comment: @cricket_007 oh you're right, meant ar! thank you for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to count the numbers in a dictionary, and sum the number of pairs found, which must be a multiple of two.

More specifically, you can [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) up the pairs from a [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object. Remember that we use `//` for floor division to round down to the correct number of pairs.

**Sample Implementation**

```
from collections import Counter

def sum_pairs(lst):
    return sum(v // 2 for v in Counter(lst).values())
```

**Tests**

```
>>> sum_pairs([10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20, 20])
4
>>> sum_pairs([10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20, 20, 20])
4
>>> sum_pairs([10, 20, 20, 10, 10, 30, 50, 10, 20])
3
>>> sum_pairs([10, 20, 30, 50])
0
>>> sum_pairs([10, 20, 30, 50, 10])
1
```

**Note:** Just for clarity, `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`. Its the simplest way to count items from a list.